# constant expression required while using constants

Tags: switch-statement, case, constants, final

> private static int counter = 0;
>  public static **final** int
>   CLIENT_REQUEST_TIME = counter++;
>
> ...
>
> switch (command) {
>  case Command.CLIENT_REQUEST_TIME:
>
> ...

but here it comes the

> "Error:(20, 25) java: constant expression required",

for the case statement.

but why on earth? since CLIENT_REQUEST_TIME is constant

I know this is something that should be rather addressed to Oracle and I can choose from millions of workarounds... but just in case someone can see some logic behind, it will certainly make me sleep better tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because you set not constant property to constant field. I am not understand what this code must to do, but possibly you can change it to look like this:

`private static int counter = 0;
    public static int CLIENT_REQUEST_TIME = counter++;`